# on change submit is not working

Tags: javascript

is there any mistake in write in `this.form.submit();`?

This is my select box i want to submit form on change but from is not submited on change. I don't know whats is wrong in that.

```
<select name="workerId" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option value="">Select Worker Name</option>
    {html_options values=$workerArray.workerId output=$workerArray.workerName}
</select>
```

Comment: It works fine. Please make sure that you have multiple values in <select><option> which can be changed to test the submit() function.

Comment: Did you check for errors in your browser's console? Is there a `<form>` element in your code? What you've posted is incomplete.

Comment: there is no error @j08691

Comment: uncaught exception: Not a valid URL: http://localhost/gold6/processEntry.php  @j08691